# Number of items in a list filtered AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filtering

How do you get the length/number of items returned by a filter predictate in AngularJS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

Comment: How can an earlier question be a duplicate? This was posted a month earlier the question you are citing.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I managed to find a great answer on the AngularJS Google Group, thanks to Pawel Kozlowski.

```
ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)"
```

Would create the `filtered` list on the fly, you can use `filtered.length` anywhere else in the current scope to show the count.

Comment: could you please add the reference? That would be great.

Comment: @htellez - sorry, I can't. However, there's nothing missing from the post, that isn't in this answer.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to set the "filtered" array to return 0 until the search is initiated?

Comment: Thanks, @Slomojo, I want to know how to pass this filtered variable to parent scope. (I'm doing the filter in a directive)

Comment: @Rocky see the answer by EpokK, use the Javascript side to do that.  Placing more logic in the view template is unwise.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<span ng-bind="nb"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.nb = $filter('filter')(items, filterExpr).length;
```

## Documentation

**In HTML Template Binding**

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : array : expression : comparator}}
```

**In JavaScript**

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Answer (score 4):

i also had to display the length of a filtered array and this one worked for me:

```
{{ (items | filter:filterExpr).length }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of facts, this will work with display filter(`orderBy`, `limitTo`)

```
item in list = ( item_array|filter:some_str) | orderBy: pref | limitTo: nItemToDisplay
```

if you need to display 5 items at a time, you still can use list.length. Usefull for pagination or in datatable.