# How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data array which contains many objects (JSON format). The following can be assumed as  the contents of this array:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Jim",
    "age" : 25
  },
  {
    "name": "Jerry",
    "age": 27
  }
];
```

Now, I display these details as:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter: query">
</div
```

Here, query is modeled to an input field in which the user can restrict the data displayed.

Now, I have another location in which I display the current count of people / person being display, i.e `Showing {{data.length}} Persons`

What I want to do is that when the user searches for a person and the data displayed is filtered based on the query, the `Showing...persons` also change the value of people being shown currently. But it is not happening. It always displays the total persons in data rather than the filtered one - how do I get the count of filtered data?

Answer (score 757):

**For Angular 1.3+** (credits to @Tom)

Use an *alias expression* (Docs: [Angular 1.3.0: ngRepeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), scroll down to the *Arguments* section):

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter:query as filtered">
</div>
```

**For Angular prior to 1.3**

Assign the results to a new variable (e.g. `filtered`) and access it:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in filtered = (data | filter: query)">
</div>
```

Display the number of results:

```
Showing {{filtered.length}} Persons
```

Fiddle a [similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/Nk8qy/3/). Credits go to [Pawel Kozlowski](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7WY_BmFzd3U)

Comment: This is the simple answer that doesn't repeat filter execution.

Comment: What if I now need to access the value of `filtered.length` inside of my controller? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Ben: Yes. You can access it inside the controller using `$scope.filtered.length`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Logs `undefined`, likely because at the time of logging it, the variable isn't defined yet. So how would I ensure the code in the controller is run *after* the variable was defined and the filter was applied in the view?

Comment: @Ben: I guess this is going off-topic. I'd consider creating a custom filter e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/), however, you could also watch it inside the controller: `$scope.$watch('filtered', function() { console.log('filtered:', $scope.filtered); });`

Comment: I had problems getting `$scope.$watch` to work so I used `ng-keyup` on the search input instead

Comment: This works for named controllers too, using this syntax: `ng-repeat="person in ctrl.filtered = (data | filter: query)"`.

Comment: Perfect +1, also I should mention for others it may be less obvious but when placing () around your data filters, and you are doing pagination, don't include the pagination inside the ().

Comment: this is what a perfect answer looks like. Clean, clear and concise. Saved me a lot of effort. Well done mate!!

Comment: The 1.3+ version didn't work if I wanted to add limitTo : `person in data | filter:query as filtered | limitTo:5`. So I had to use the prior to 1.3 version: `person in filtered = (data | filter: query) | limitTo: 5`

Comment: @benjovanic thanks. I was trying the same thing just now (with a limitTo 5 at the end, too!)  Your comment was helpful.

Comment: How would I make this work if I want filtered.length available on the parent of the ng-repeat div?

Answer (score 337):

For completeness, in addition to previous answers (perform calculation of visible people inside controller) you can also perform that calculations in your HTML template as in the example below.

Assuming your list of people is in `data` variable and you filter people using `query` model, the following code will work for you:

```
<p>Number of visible people: {{(data|filter:query).length}}</p>
<p>Total number of people: {{data.length}}</p>
```

- `{{data.length}}` - prints total number of people
- `{{(data|filter:query).length}}` - prints filtered number of people

**Note** that this solution works fine if you want to use filtered data **only once** in a page. However, if you use filtered data more than once e.g. to present items and to show length of filtered list, I would suggest using **alias expression** (described below) for AngularJS **1.3+** or the solution proposed by *@Wumms* for AngularJS version prior to 1.3.

**New Feature in Angular 1.3**

AngularJS creators also noticed that problem and in version [1.3 (beta 17)](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) they added "alias" expression which will store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied e.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter:query as results">
    <!-- template ... -->
</div>

<p>Number of visible people: {{results.length}}</p>
```

The **alias expression** will prevent multiple filter execution issue.

I hope that will help.

Comment: Will this mean the filter is executed twice?

Comment: Yes, it is executed twice.

Comment: make sure you read @Wumms answer before you decide to use this one (and you won't)...

Comment: @epeleg Why would/should we decide to use Wumms' answer over this one? As far as I can tell the two answers' examples are functionally equivalent, except I can find this answer as a documented feature of ngRepeat but I can't find anything about variable assignments in an ngRepeat expression being something officially condoned.

Comment: Nevermind, I see the answer didn't contain the part about the alias expression when you made your comment.

Comment: Yep, but I am glad you asked... I was not familiar with the alias expression.
It is a good Q what should happen to Q's where the correct answer changes over time... should the person that provided the best answer (for when the Q was asked) loose his reputation because the correct answer he gave in the past is no longer the best? maybe there should be a difference between the accepted answer and the currently most accurate answer...

Comment: Great, and this is cool because it works for `collection-repeat` too!

Comment: Great anwer! Especially the one that you could use filter just like that, without any ng-repeat or similar. +1

Comment: This answer supports multiple filter expressions unlike the current top answer. i.e) `{{(data|filter:query|filter:query2).length}}`

Answer (score 50):

The easiest way if you have

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data | filter: query"></div>
```

Filtered data length

```
<div>{{ (data | filter: query).length }}</div>
```

Comment: This is most useful for anyone using angular utils dir-paginate directive as the aliasing and the pre ng-1.3 alternative are not supported.

Comment: Will this enumerate the data twice?

Answer (score 36):

ngRepeat creates a copy of the array when it applies a filter, so you can't use the source array to reference only the filtered elements.

In your case, in may be better to apply the filter inside of your controller using the [`$filter`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filter) service:

```js
function MainCtrl( $scope, filterFilter ) {
  // ...

  $scope.filteredData = myNormalData;

  $scope.$watch( 'myInputModel', function ( val ) {
    $scope.filteredData = filterFilter( myNormalData, val );
  });

  // ...
}
```

And then you use the `filteredData` property in your view instead. Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7c1l24rPkuKPOS5o2qtx?p=preview

Comment: What I understood is that I use `{{filteredData.length}}` instead of `data.length`. I also understood that `myInputModel` is the model mapped to the input query which filters the data. `val` would be the text that is typed in the input (basically query) but each time I type, it changes. But what is `filterFilter` here? I might add that I have my own customFilter created (wherein I can specify which key of the object to consider for filtering).

Comment: That's right. Also just use `ng-repeat="person in filteredData"` as there is no sense filtering it twice. With the `$filter` service, you can ask for a specific filter by just suffixing it with "Filter", e.g.: `dateFilter`, `jsonFilter`, etc. If you are using your own custom filter, just use that one instead of the generic `filterFilter`.

Comment: What about applying multiple filters to one ng-repeat, say you have 2 dropdowns with values and one text input field?

Comment: The filter is just a function, so you'd just pass the output of the first filter to the second filter.

Answer (score 29):

Since AngularJS 1.3 you can use aliases:

```
item in items | filter:x as results
```

and somewhere:

```
<span>Total {{results.length}} result(s).</span>
```

From [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> You can also provide an
>   optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate
>   results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically
>   this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on
>   the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> For example: item in items | filter:x as results will store the
>   fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items
>   have been processed through the filter.

Comment: I am unable to apply `$scope.$watch` to this aliased result.  Any tips for `$broadcast`ing the aliased `results` variable?

Answer (score 25):

It is also useful to note that you can store multiple levels of results by grouping filters

```
all items: {{items.length}}
filtered items: {{filteredItems.length}}
limited and filtered items: {{limitedAndFilteredItems.length}}
<div ng-repeat="item in limitedAndFilteredItems = (filteredItems = (items | filter:search) | limitTo:25)">...</div>
```

here's a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxzby80p/)

Answer (score 13):

Here is worked example [See on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFqrq6p0RwVVldF4526S?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="search" type="text">
    <br>
    Showing {{data.length}} Persons; <br>
    Filtered {{counted}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in data | filter:search">
        {{person.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

<script> 
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', [])

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      "name": "Jim", "age" : 21
    }, {
      "name": "Jerry", "age": 26
    }, {
      "name": "Alex",  "age" : 25
    }, {
      "name": "Max", "age": 22
    }
  ];

  $scope.counted = $scope.data.length; 
  $scope.$watch("search", function(query){
    $scope.counted = $filter("filter")($scope.data, query).length;
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're running the filter twice: once in the ngRepeat and once in the controller.

Comment: Yea, you're right, can you post your working example based on your answer, i'd like to learn a bit more filters? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Here's the working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7c1l24rPkuKPOS5o2qtx?p=preview. I just edited yours.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with **2 ways**. In **template** and in **Controller**. In template you can set your filtered array to another variable, then use it like you want. Here is how to do it:

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="user in usersList = (users | gender:filterGender)" data-ng-bind="user.name"></li>
</ul>
 ....
<span>{{ usersList.length | number }}</span>
```

If you need examples, see the [AngularJs filtered count examples/demos](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/how-to-show-angularjs-filtered-count.html)