# ng-grid gridData only refeshing sometimes

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid that I am trying to fill with some search results. 
The queries work as long as the result has a different amount of rows...
If a query has the same amount of rows as the previous query... the result will not show.

```
    // after a rest call 
    // we have the result
    // #1 Clean gridData and local array
      $scope.gridData.length = 0;    
      _labels.length = 0;

    // #2 feed the grid 
    // these two functions add rows to the grid + data to the rows (and my local array) 
            addLabels(result.Labels);
            addPhrases(result.Phrases);


    // Second version attempting to call $scope.$apply
    // does not work either

      $scope.gridData.length = 0;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }

        _labels.length = 0;
        addLabels(result.Labels);
        addPhrases(result.Phrases);
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
```

here is a plunker that demonstrates this: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gSFtuL?p=preview

note that if you push one more (or one less) item, the grid refreshes

Comment: Do you have gripOptions defined?  Can you show that and your markup?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ngGrid specifically watches the array.length before it passes in the options.data. Copied from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/ng-grid-2.0.7.debug.js):

```
$scope.$parent.$watch(options.data, dataWatcher);
$scope.$parent.$watch(options.data + '.length', function() {
    dataWatcher($scope.$eval(options.data));
});
```

I can't explain why, but it works for me if I assign an empty array in stead of the resetting the arrays length.  Like this:

```
  $scope.changeData = function() {
    /* $scope.myData.length =0; -- this doesn't work */
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.myData.push({name: "aMoroni", age: 51});
    $scope.myData.push({name: "bMoroni", age: 52});
    $scope.myData.push({name: "cMoroni", age: 53});
    $scope.myData.push({name: "dMoroni", age: 54});
    $scope.myData.push({name: "eMoroni", age: 55});
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this as an issue on ng-grids github site. It turned out that others had had the same problem, and that there is a solution:
(you need to get your hands dirty though and alter the ng-grid code.)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/632

Im guessing it will make it into version 3.0

Comment: Using $watch with the objectEquality parameter set to true is an expensive operations though. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721295/angularjs-watch-not-being-triggered-for-changes-to-an-array-of-objects