# How i get the count of a filterd data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a dataarray which i pass to a ng-repeat to have the data on site.
I also have a searchmodel and filter the data with that. Works nice so far but i want to execute a function when i am in the searchfield and press enter. so long i have results which match i want to alert the first ename attribute from this entry. when result is 0 i want to alert New entry: "what i have written"
minimized code you can see here:
http://jsbin.com/aDEdiJO/1/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to display length of filtered data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSbin of your example working: http://jsbin.com/aDEdiJO/4/edit

The way to do it which is outlined [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7WY_BmFzd3U) is to change your ng-repeat code from:

```
ng-repeat="entity in entities | filter:esearch"
```

To be:

```
ng-repeat="entity in selection = (entities | filter:esearch)"
```

and then you can use: `{{selection.length}}` anywhere to get the length.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your filter expression in parenthesis `(` `)` and use the `length` attribute on the aarry returned

```
(myArr|filter:1).length
```

Here is a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/EFmtf/
The array has a length of 4, the filtered array has a length of 3, you can see the values printed.

Here is your example, modified: http://jsbin.com/aDEdiJO/8/edit

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry.
I searched not long enough. I found the answer here.
[How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)
shame over me...

josh thank You for ur answer - but i want the logic in Controller not in the view.