# Angular.js. How to count ng-repeat iterations which satisfy the custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-show="?" ng-repeat="item in items | notEmpty">
</div>
```

Filter:

```
Kb.filter("notEmpty", function(){ 
  return function(input){
    var output=[];
    for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
      if(input[i]){
        output.push(input[i]);
      }
    }
    return output;
}});
```

I need to show/hide repeated s according the quantity of filtered items in the loop. 
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`ng-repeat` expression allows filtered results to be assigned to a variable. This variable will be accessible from current scope so you can use it in same scope anyway you want:

```html
<p>Number of filtered items: {{filteredItems.length}}</p>

<div 
  ng-show="filteredItems.length > 0" 
  ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | notEmpty)"
>
 {{$index}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that i can do such syntax: `ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | notEmpty)`

Comment: Thanks! can't believe that we had such a syntax

Comment: Who on earth would invent such a syntax? Crazy, isn't it? `<div ng-repeat="entry in filteredItemCounters[$index] = (day.items | filter:filterItemsFn) | orderBy:['-meta.ago', 'meta.review', 'meta.star', '-orig.iso']" ng-init="orig=entry.orig; meta=entry.meta;">`

Comment: As of Angular 1.3 you can use `variable in expression as alias_expression`

Comment: Perfect. Worked as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way may be to run the filter in your controller. Something like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, notEmptyFilter)
{
    //$scope.items is put into the scope somehow
    $scope.filteredItems = notEmptyFilter($scope.items);
}
```

Then your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div ng-show="filteredItems.length > 0" ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Angular 1.3 you can use following syntax for `ng-repeat`:

```
variable in expression as alias_expression
```

That is:

```
<p>Number of filtered items: {{filteredItems.length}}</p>

<div ng-repeat="item in items | notEmpty as filteredItems">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this

[How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data/31920875#31920875) ,

that describes to get the count after filtering the list