# Angularjs get length of returned filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I'm using ng-repeat to create a list of entires and using a filter.

Is it possible to get the number of entries returned, like a length

```
    data-ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter: { country_code : countryCode }"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js. How to count ng-repeat iterations which satisfy the custom filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664691/angular-js-how-to-count-ng-repeat-iterations-which-satisfy-the-custom-filter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is little bit tricky, use `ng-init`:

```
ng-init="filter_len = (entries | filter: { country_code : countryCode }).length"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3Nx/

Answer (score 4):

As you know *filter* responsible to "filter" the input list and it returns filtered list where objects have the same structure. Otherwise you get digest cycle reentering that causes Exceptions (aka > 10 cycles).

**1st way**

Get length  after filtering:

```
<pre>{{(entries| myfilter:types).length }}</pre>
```

See <kbd>[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2IXe7bnZI72wDTxZVECk?p=preview)</kbd>

**2nd way**

Use custom filter and get length from there.

```
iApp.filter('myfilter', function() {

   return function( entries) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(entries, function(entry) {
          filtered.push(entry);
    });

    // here fetch list length

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the following code will work for you:

`<p>Filtered number: {{(entries|filter:{country_code:countryCode}).length}}</p>`
`<p>Total number: {{entries.length}}</p>`