# AngularJS : Binding a variable in template to increase performances

Tags: angularjs, templates, variables, binding

Here is a code sample I use:

```
<div ng-class="{alert: ((elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length / elements.length) > maxPercentAlerts}">

{{(elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length}}

({{Math.floor((elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length * 100 / elements.length)}} %)

</div>
```

As you see, I need to filter my 'elements' array 3 times. I would like to use this kind of following code to increase perfs: 
*(this is just an example of what I need, not real code)*

```
<div some-ng-prop="alertCount=(elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length"
    <div ng-class="{alert: (alertCount / elements.length) > maxPercentAlerts}">

    {{alertCount}}

    ({{Math.floor(alertCount * 100 / elements.length)}} %)

</div>
```

I've tried to handle it with the 'ng-init' attribute: it worked great... But when my model changes, the values are not updated.

Is there a way to do that ?

I've tried to be clear, but please ask for details if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js. How to count ng-repeat iterations which satisfy the custom filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664691/angular-js-how-to-count-ng-repeat-iterations-which-satisfy-the-custom-filter)

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: I updated my plunker with buttons to change the collection and to see the filter counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bNjSnee5UwVjp6wHE6RK

#### I created a directive:

- I use `$parse` rather than `$eval` for optimizations.
- You provide a collection to watch and an expression to run on each change.
- It works like `ngInit` only it updates when the **collection** is dirty.
- I chose general names for attributes, you can change it to what you like.

**directive**:

```
app.directive('watchCollection', function($parse){
  return {
    compile: function(tElm,tAttrs){

      if(! tAttrs.assign) return;

      var assignFn = $parse(tAttrs.assign)

      return function(scope,elm,attrs){      
        scope.$watchCollection(tAttrs.watchCollection , function(val){
          assignFn(scope);
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**html**:

```
<div watch-collection="elements" 
     assign="alertCount=(elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length">
```

Answer (score 0):

Stewie suggested it was a duplicate, I think it's not but it made me try the following code which works great :

```
<div ng-class="{alert: (alertCount / elements.length) > maxPercentAlerts}">

{{alertCount = (elements|filter:{hasAlert: true}).length}}

({{Math.floor(alertCount * 100 / elements.length)}} %)

</div>
```

Comment: That's even worse for performance as it would run on each $digest. There could be many $digests with each digest cycle

Comment: Now I realize that it would always run, even if the collection hasn't changed.