# Update UI based on change of a directive attribute in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I am struggling with data binding in AngularJs.

I have the following piece of markup in .html file that includes the custom directive:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="i in object" attr-1="{{i.some_variable}}"></my-directive>
```

**Note**: 'some-variable' is being updated every 10 seconds(based on the associate collection and passed to template through controller).

The directive's code includes:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {

  scope: {
   'attr-1': '=attr1'
```

which [throws this exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=i&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=4&p3=%7B$%20i.some_value%20$%7D&p4=i.some_value%20$%7D) because of the brackets in attr-1(see html code above).

It works though if I use read-only access(note at sign below):

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {

  scope: {
   'attr-1': '@attr1'
```

I use scope.attr-1 in directive's HTML to show its value.

The problem is that with read-only access UI is not reflecting the change in attribute change.

I've found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408274/angularjs-binding-a-variable-in-template-to-increase-performances) with $parse or $eval(couldn't make them work tho). Is there a better one there?

Comment: One thing you can do is rewrite your directive to require ng-model. That should handle the updating issues you have.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Would probably work but I wanted to preserve an isolated scope in the directive I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the following solution(in case somebody runs into the the same problem):

```
// Directive's code

myApp.directive('myDir', function () { return {
    restrict: 'E',

    templateUrl: function () {
        return 'my-dir.html';
    },
    scope: {
        'id': '@arId',
        'x': '@arX',
        'y': '@arY',
        //....
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

         // *** SOLUTION ***
         attrs.$observe('arId', function (id) {
             $scope.id = id;
         });
         //...
    }
```

**Update**: somebody sent me this answer, they have the same problem and came up with a very similar if not exact same solution:

[Using a directive inside an ng-repeat, and a mysterious power of scope '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502559/using-a-directive-inside-an-ng-repeat-and-a-mysterious-power-of-scope)

It is useful to read because they explain what's the idea behind it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need only two-way binding and I think `$parse` or `$eval` is not needed.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/sxjz1zhe/).

It uses `$interval` to simulate your updating but the update can also come from other sources e.g. web socket or ajax request.

I'm using `controllerAs` and `bindToController` syntax (AngularJs version 1.4 or newer required) but the same is also possible with just an isolated scope. See [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in angular docs.

The `$watch` in the controller of the directive is only to show how the directive can detect that the data have changed.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', MainController)
 .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function MainController($interval) {
 var self = this,
        refreshTime = 1000; //interval time in ms
    
    activate();
    
    function activate() {
     this.data = 0;
     $interval(updateView, refreshTime);
    }
    
    function updateView() {
     self.data = Math.round(Math.random()*100, 0);
    }
}

function myDirective() {
 return {
     restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        },
        bindToController: {
            data: '='
        },
        template: '<div><p>directive data: {{directiveCtrl.data}}</p></div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('directiveCtrl.data', function(newValue) {
             console.log('data changed', newValue);
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'directiveCtrl'
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
    model value in ctrl. {{ctrl.data}}
    <my-directive data="ctrl.data"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is very descriptive but I believe this solved a different problem. I updated the question with some details to make it more accurate. For example, ng-repeat is the important detail here since it's leading to the problem. Also, I use templateUrl because it's many lines of html code that I don't want to store in directive.js due to maintainability reasons.

Comment: I've created another jsfiddle with `ng-repeat`. Please have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/eL8f0krr/). I think it's doing what you're looking for.