# Dynamically hiding a list depending on the values in the list in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<ul>` of elements in html with roughly the structure as follows:

```
<ul id="ElementList">
  <li> Some element 1 </li>
  <li> Some element 2 </li>
  <li> Some element 3 </li>
  <li ng-repeat="element in someArray" ng-show = "SomeCondition"> element </li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide the Element list completely if there is no element after element 3 and show the complete list if there is any element seen after element 3. The array used for ng-repeat and the condition for ng-show above are something that I cannot make use of or rather understand how it works (comes from a third party) and hence can play around only with what is rendered. How can I do this?

Comment: Solved using answers for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664691/angular-js-how-to-count-ng-repeat-iterations-which-satisfy-the-custom-filter

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the list to be shown only if the array of elements is not empty, and if SomeCondition is true:

```
<ul id="ElementList" ng-show="someArray.length != 0 && SomeCondition">
```

Comment: The condition clause here works on a particular element and not the array as a whole. So, say there 10 elements in the array but none of them meet the condition, they won't appear in the list and in this case, I do not want to show element 1, element 2 and element 3 also.

Comment: Then add a function to the controller scope that returns true if at least one element satisfies its condition.

Comment: Making changes to the controller might make things very complicated for me. Is there any way, like say associate a model with the list elements and say check things against that model?