# Find number of columns produced by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div on which i used ng-repeat. It displays the list of photos in a grid. This is all very simple stuff and working fine.

I need to add file explorer like navigation on the items inside the grid. The easiest way would be to know the length of a line (number of items in the line) and then do simple math to calculate where to move the selection based on the key pressed.

The problem i'm having is finding out the length of the line. Is it even doable?

Edit :

```
<div class="images-cq__item" ng-repeat="photo in displayedPhotos">
    <div ng-class="{active: photo.selected}" id="{{photo.uuid}}" ng-click="selectionEvent({value: photo.uuid, event: $event, index: $index})">
    <div class="images-cq-statut" ng-show="photo.statusCQ != 'none'">
        {{photo.statusCQ}}
    </div>
    <div class="img-cq">
        <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbPath100}}" alt="Alternate Text" />
        <a href="#" class="zoom-cq" title="zoom" ng-click="zoomOpen({value: $index, event: $event})">zoom</a>
    </div>
    <p>
        {{photo.title}}
    </p>
    <ul class="images-cq-tags">
        <li id="{{photo.uuid}}.{{tag.value}}" ng-repeat="tag in tags" style="display:none">
            <span>{{tag.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The displayedPhotos is a simple array with photo objects obtained from the server. It contains several links (thumbnails, original), and some other info but i don't think it is relevant in this case.

Comment: Not doable without the code i'd say.

Comment: Do you mean my code?

Comment: Probably... You should include the code you want us to test against.

Comment: Added the html pertaining to the case, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/4gbw8abx/1/) is what i got:

JavaScript

```
var items = $(".images-cq__item");
var previousTop = null;
var itemsPerRow = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++){
  var item = items.eq(i);
  var offset = item.offset();
  var top = offset.top;

  if(!previousTop || (top == previousTop)){
    previousTop = top;
    itemsPerRow++;
  } else{
    break;
  }
}

console.log(itemsPerRow); // 3
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
  <div class="images-cq__item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width: 400px;
}

.images-cq__item{
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: green;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't know there is something as handy as .offset(). This answers perfectly my question. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote also if this helped you :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{$index}}` inside `ng-repeat`

See this [Angular.js. How to count ng-repeat iterations which satisfy the custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664691/angular-js-how-to-count-ng-repeat-iterations-which-satisfy-the-custom-filter)

Comment: What i'm looking for is not that kind of length. Let's say i have 50 elements, they will be displayed 7 per line. What i need to find is '7' as length. This length depends on many things (simply using ctrl + mouse wheel to zoom in will reduce length to 3).

Comment: This does not answer the question. Comment to downvote.