# Angular ng-repeat element count

Tags: angularjs

```
<li ng-repeat="Item in Items">
        <div ng-switch="($index)==0">
            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                <a href="#"><   Previous</a>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="false">
                <a href="#">{{$index}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

I want to get element count of the Items and want to show "Next >" for last item

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="Item in Items">
                <a ng-if="$first" href="#"><   Previous</a>
                <a ng-if="!$first && !$last" href="#">{{$index}}</a>
                <a ng-if="$last" href="#">Next ></a>
    </li>
```

To get the length use `Items.length`. It becomes more complex if there is a filter. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

Comment: Thanks Chandermani. Problem solved. I used $first and $last in ng-switch because i cant use ng-if in my version. Thanks a lot