# Checking if an ng-repeat yields empty set after filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do this:

- ng-repeat a list of about 50 items
- Filter it based on a text field (`ng-repeat="note in notes|filter:basicFilter"`)
- If the basic filter yields no results (or maybe like 5 results), perform an $http call to do a deep search on the database

Is there a way to check what the filter yields after the "basic" filter, so I can perform a $http call back to the server? Is there a "filter" that is built-in to angular that I can call up?

I've tried watching the variable:

```
  $scope.$watch('filtered_notes', function() {
    // can't do this
  });
```

Where `ng-repeat="note in filtered_notes = (notes | orderBy:['-note_time']|filter:noteFilter|limitTo:limit)"`

But, it throws an error: `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to display length of filtered data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

Comment: You can write custom filter `app.filter("myCustomFilter", ....)`

Comment: @MikeCheel I'm not trying to display the length, I would like a callback that will be called once it's done filtering

Comment: That stack post should give you enough to go on though

Comment: I'm not sure that it does. I've tried $watching the variable created after the filter, but it throws an exception.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Oooh, that worked. If you want to put it in an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @RalphWiggum posted answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom filter like following example

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="note in filtered_notes |  myCustomFilter:theInput">
```

**custom filter JS**

```
 iApp.filter('myCustomFilter', function() {
   return function( notes, input) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(notes, function(item) {
       if(/* do any condition with 'input' */) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }

    });

    if(filtered.length >= 5 ){
         /* do HTTP call or use $broadcast to trigger HTTP call*/
    }

    return filtered;
  };
```