# Angular js - Show message if ng-repeat is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following AngularJS application is working with ng-repeat and an applied filter. A certain applied filter leaves no values left. How can I display a notification?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9daLbLm/1/)

HTML

```
<div >
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">


    <ul >
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in values | filter:filterIds()"> 
            <code>#{{item.id}}</code> Item
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p ng-show="!values.length">no vals with this filter</p>
    <button ng-click="loadNewFilter()"> filter now</button>
</div>


</div>
```

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('m', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.values = [{
    id: 1
}, ....
}];

$scope.filter = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$scope.filterIds = function (ids) {
        return function (item) {
            var filter = $scope.filter;

                 return filter.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;         
        }
 }

$scope.loadNewFilter = function (){
    $scope.filter = [-1];
    $scope.$apply();
}

});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.values = [
    {id: 1}, 
    {id: 2}, 
    {id: 3}, 
    {id: 4}, 
    {id: 5}, 
    {id: 6}];
    
  $scope.filter = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
        
  $scope.filterIds = function (ids) {
    return function (item) {
      var filter = $scope.filter; 
      return filter.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;        
    }
  }
        
  $scope.loadNewFilter = function (){
    $scope.filter = [1,5];    
  }                 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">               
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in testValue=(values | filter:filterIds())"> 
        <code>#{{item.id}}</code> Item
      </li>
    </ul>           
    <p ng-show="!testValue.length">no vals with this filter</p>
    <button ng-click="loadNewFilter()"> filter now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[***FIDDLE LINK***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/ff9dhp32/)

[***This is Another one FIDDLE LINK check this also***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/tue3jhy1/)

Comment: I would update that code, to show two messages, one if no 'values' initially exist  <p ng-show="!values.length">no values exist</p>,  another if values exist, but all are filtered out <p ng-show="values.length && !testValue.length">no vals with this filter</p>

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin Check this Updated
***FIDDLE LINK***
http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/z9daLbLm/13/

Answer (score 29):

I would go with very simple CSS approach:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in values | filter:filterIds()"> <code>#{{item.id}}</code> Item</li>
    <li class="no-items">There are no matching items.</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li + .no-items {
    display: none;
}
```

So basically `li.no-items` is only visible if there are no other `LI`'s and hidden otherwise. I think this is better for performance than introducing one more watcher with `ngShow/ngHide`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z9daLbLm/5/

Comment: You can add `.loading{display:none}` to prevent showing the message while loading

Comment: I like this best if there are multiple filters being done, its a true look at the DOM state without actually needing to investigate with overhead.

Answer (score 8):

Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/z9daLbLm/2/

You can save the result of the filter in `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filteredValues = (values | filter:filterIds())">{{item}}</div>
```

The result is stored in `filteredValues`
Then use this filtered values in the DOM

```
<div ng-show="!filteredValues.length">No Items</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/ntofav3c/

change this:

```
<p ng-show="!values.length">no vals with this filter</p>
```

to:

```
 <p ng-hide="values | filter:filterIds()">no vals with this filter</p>
```

Comment: I like this approach the best as its much more meaningful in the Angular sense but unfortunately gets cluttered when you have multiple filters upon the ng-repeat list.

Answer (score 2):

See this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9daLbLm/4/
I added this code before your `<ul>` list

```
<div ng-if="(values|filter:filterIds()).length == 0">
    List is empty
</div>
```

It just shows "List is empty" text when your filtered values length is zero.

For more information refer to this link: [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use ng-switch to do this.

*For example:*

```
`    <div ng-app ng-controller="friendsCtrl">
    <label>Search: </label><input ng-model="searchText" type="text">
    <div ng-init="filtered = (friends | filter:searchText)">
    <h3>'Found '{{(friends | filter:searchText).length}} friends</h3>
    <div ng-switch="(friends | filter:searchText).length">
      <span class="ng-empty" ng-switch-when="0">No friends</span>
      <table ng-switch-default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same kind of problems..
I had three filters and one orderBy in the ng-repeat and wanted to show some emptyList Messages....

The above solutions didnot work..so I made one out of my own.

- Made the emptymsg as background div and the mainContainer as top div..
- The emptyMsg div will always be shown, so whenever there is no value in list.. the emptyMsg will be the only div showing.
  PS: the code snippet wont run..because the additional libraries are not added.. This is just to give you an idea!

  ```css
  //empty msg....
  .emptyMsg{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      color: gray;
      text-align: center;
      font-size:3.0em;
      z-index: 0;
  }
  .activityItem {
      margin: 0px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
      border: 0px !important;
  }
  .mainContainer {
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      left: 0px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h4>List of Activities</h4>
          <ion-list>
             <div class="emptyMsg">No Activities found!</div>
              <div class="item activityItem" ng-repeat="activity in activities | orderBy:field1Order:order.reverse1 | filter:importanceFilter | filter:motiveFilter track by $index">
                     <div class="mainContainer">

                              <div class="divBar">{{activity.energy}}%</div>
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
              
          </ion-list>
  ```