# Check for empty ng-repeat from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a newbie in angularjs. And my template is something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in values"></div>
<div ng-repeat="item1 in values1"></div>
```

And my controller:

```
$scope.openItems = function () {
    $http.get('/api/openItems').success(function (data) {
         $scope.values = data;
    });
};
```

That is working fine. Now I want to show the items, only if it is empty.

I tried something like this:

```
$scope.openItems = function () {
    $http.get('/api/openItems').success(function (data) {
    if ($scope.values.length == 0) {
         $scope.values = data;
    } else {
         $scope.values1 = data;
    }
    });
};
```

Any idea how to check from the controller is a ng-repeat has data in it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"Now I want to show the items, only if it is empty."_ could you clarify what you mean by that, because I am interpreting that you only want to show the repeat if it is empty?

Comment: You don't really need controller to check it: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866317/949476) is the most optimal approach.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I mean If the first div is empty I want to show the data in it. If the first div has data, I want to show the data in the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your array is initialized (which we're not seeing) it might not ever have length==0 (for example I think it could be undefined, etc.) you could try:

```
if ($scope.values.length != 0) {
        $scope.values1 = data; 
    } else {
        $scope.values = data;
    }
```

Comment: My array seems to be not initialized. It's created when the ajax call returns data.

Comment: You was right...I should check for undefined. So 

   if (!$scope.values1) {$scope.values1 = data; return;}
Make de magic.Thanks !

Comment: @user1246072 don't check for undefined, initialize the scope variables before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are initializing the arrays at the top, then you can just do something like this :

```
 //initialize vars
 $scope.values = [];
 $scope.values1 = [];


$scope.openItems = function () {
    $http.get('/api/openItems').success(function (data) {
    if ($scope.values.length === 0) {
         //you may or may not want to clear the second array if you are toggling back and forth
         $scope.values1 = [];
         $scope.values = data;
    } else {
         //empty the first one so we make the hide/show logic simple
         $scope.values = [];
         $scope.values1 = data;
    }
    });
};
```

then your html just looks like

```
<div ng-show="values.length" ng-repeat="item in values"></div>
<div ng-show="values1.length" ng-repeat="item1 in values1"></div>
```

Here is a quick proof of concept - http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/573/

You can also swap the ng-show with ng-if, if you want the divs to actually be taken off the DOM.