# Filter Data in AngularJs Using Dropdown list value

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement filtering in angularJs.I searched from googling but not found any ways in which i want.

> when controller is load i get data from my web service call. Now i
>   have 3 dropdowns like Status,Company,Area. Now , i want to do that if
>   i select any status from dropdown the table data which is bind on load
>   will filter based on that status and same as other two dropdowns.

So, how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ng-repeat="x in list | filter:{status:selectedStatus, company:selectedCompany}"
```

Where `selectedStatus` and `seletedCompany` are dropdown `ng-model` name.

Keep in mind status and company should be a property of all data.

Comment: if there is no record found then when i want to display No data found message

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866121/angular-js-show-message-if-ng-repeat-is-empty&ved=0ahUKEwiMms-RnPzKAhXWBY4KHbnDB3QQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNH7ZVDZnu0z2oBl_MMvDED3Pmffdg&sig2=b3vDxhe5IW2Jl1k7TxtZnA

Comment: i have my ng-repeat like ng-repeat="accident in current_accident   | filter :  {IsActive : status, RegionId  : user.ClientRegion , ClientName : user.Company} " but No Record Found does not work for me. i used like <div ng-show="!accident.length">There is no Accidents Found.</div>. so, what i am doing wrong in this ?

Comment: i have fixed it. but one problem is i used Footable pagination and if i filter the data the pagination is not work. if data found from 5 page and total records found from filter is 5 then total 5 pagination pages display even if total page size is 10.

Comment: This ia another problem.  Post new question.