# ng-show with localStorage choice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ionic list which shows the checked items from another list, but I want to show a message if the list is empty.

The code is:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat='(place, checked) in localStorage.options' ng-if="checked" class="item item-body">
```

How would I do the ng-show, as this is not the standard ng-repeat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25866317/949476 ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Controller:

```
$scope.isEmptyObjectEmpty = function(object) {
        for(var i in object) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Html:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap"
     ng-if="!isEmptyObjectEmpty(localStorage.options)">
               list is empty(msg)
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that works if the localStorage is empty, but what I want is, if the list is empty as well.

Comment: i didnt got..!means there is no other list in your ques..!to check..update your ques properly..!which list..?

Comment: for example the localStorage saves the list but what about when the list is empty. The message is not displayed

Comment: try with ng-if="!isEmptyObjectEmpty(localStorage.options) || localStorage.list.length < 0"

Comment: Update your ques with controller code, data (localstorage) , and complete html . Its hard to guess your problem, what your are trying your side..!help yourself..!