# AngularJS get length by filtering 3rd level property

Tags: angularjs, filter, count

I have been trying to get the count of items that have a specific text match for a specific field but I haven't had any luck.

The link below is the closest example I have been able to implement, but all I can get it to return is the total number of entries in the table.
[Angular Count Filtered Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

When I insert `{{data.length}}` into the view, it returns the total number of entries.
But when I change it to query the sub-field as `{{(data|filter:{team:'A'}).length}}` or `{{(data|filter:{custom_fields.team:'A'}).length}}` it returns a 0.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "custom_fields": {
        "team": ["A"]
    }
},{
    "id": 2,
    "custom_fields": {
        "team": ["B"]
    },
},{
    "id": 3,
    "custom_fields": {
        "team": ["A"]
    }
}]
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Try `{{(data|filter:{custom_fields:{team: 'A'}}).length}}`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that gives me a syntax error

Comment: If I use an input field such as: 
<input ng-model="search.custom_fields.team"></input>
{{(data|filter:search).length}}

It returns the right length, but I want the counts to load without entering anything in an Input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by filtering nested objects:

```
{{(data|filter:{custom_fields: {team: ['A']} }).length}}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUcpVcnhtEliOEfricfO?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you!  I spent far too much time and you've saved me even more!