# AngularJS - Display length of filtered data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data array which contains objects (JSON format).

```
var users = {
  'New':{
    {Name:'One'},
    {Name:'Two'}
  },
  'Old':{
    {Name:'Three'},
    {Name:'Four'}
  }
```

And i use this construction to display data:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in users">
  <p>{{key}}</p>
  <div ng-repeat="user in value | filter: query">
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the count of filtered data? 
Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10720/

```
<div ng-repeat= "user in filteredValue = (value | filter:query)"></div>
```

Just use the filtered result as another scope variable, named `filteredValue` , then you can get its length, within the scope of the controller

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<div ng-repeat="user in value | filter: query as results">` and then get `results.length`

see example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/P0ORxHkVpreANErDGc3a?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It might help you!! Its use for prints filtered number of users.

```
{{(data|filter:query).length}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/angularjs-how-to-display-length-of-filtered-data)

Assign the filtered data in a variable

```
<div ng-repeat="user in filtered = (users | filter: query)">
</div>
```

And use the `filtered.length` attribute to get the count