# How do I create a local variable with only some filters applied?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an `ng-repeat` like so:

```
item in items | filter:myFilter | page:currentPage
```

I'd like to know the current number of items that `filter:myFilter` results in for pagination.  However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517533/1216976) will result in both filters being applied (and the pagination will think there's only one page of results).

How can I conditionally apply filters to a variable created in an `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to only include some filters in your parenthesis.  In the above case, you can do something like:

```
item in filteredItems = (items | filter:myFilter) | page:currentPage
```

The result of `items | filter:myFilter` will be assigned to `filteredItems`, which is then further filtered by `page:currentPage`.

The one thing to watch out for is that `filteredItems` will be set on the parent scope of the one created by `ng-repeat` and so you'll need to be aware of collisions.