# Use ng-repeat within ng-if AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following requirement,

I have an array as customers (values such as `cust1,cust2,cust3`). 
I have textbox, in which when I enter some values it will filter the customers arraylist and displays my result (For example : if i enter `cust1` in textbox, it will display `cust1`)
If the value entered in textbox not in the arraylist (customers), i want to change textbox colour to red.
Could anyone guide to do this.

#### My approach

```
<div class="container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" /> -- I want to change this textbox colour
<br/>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : filter.name | orderBy:name">{{cust.name}} {{cust.city}}</li>
</ul>
<br/>
```

Comment: You have ng-model instead of ng-repeat `<li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : filter.name | orderBy:name">{{cust.name}} {{cust.city}}</li>`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data , use ng-if to change the color

Comment: It is ng-repeat only, i have edited it. But the link provided was not discussing on color change of ng-model text box, instead it is displaying the filtered result alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is rather simple.

First, you need to modify your `ng-repeat` in the following way:

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : filter.name | orderBy:name as filteredCustomers"
```

Notice the `as filteredCustomers` in the end. This saves the resulting filter to `$scope.filteredCustomers`.

Then, you just have to modify your input to use a conditional CSS class:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" data-ng-class="{'red': filteredCustomers.length === 0}" />
```

Also you will have to define the `.red` CSS class with `background-color: red;` or something similar.

Proof of concept: http://jsbin.com/diyehagemo/2/

Comment: Yes it is working, But When we are adding **filteredCustomers**  it does not allow order by  statement

Comment: The `orderBy` statement should also be working, but you have to put it before the `as filteredCustomers`. Have you edited the `ng-repeat` according to my answer? Also, you should **not** modify the `filteredCustomers` variable. This is just so that you can access the actual filtered AND sorted values in order to see it they are empty or not - for the purpose of colouring the input.