# How to find the length of array returned by the 'filter' filter of AngularJS?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am using the 'filter' filter of AngularJS like this:

`<li ng-repeat='item in items | filter: searchTerm'></li>`

Now, how do I find out the length of array returned by the filter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the length of items? or of returned items.?

Comment: returned `items` from the filter.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one

```
<li ng-repeat='item in ($parent.filterR=(items | filter: searchTerm))' >
</li>

{{filterR.length}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, a more simple solution:

```
<li ng-repeat='item in filtered = (items | filter: searchText)'></li>
```

Then:

```
{{filtered.length}}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat='item in items | filter: searchTerm' check>
</li>
```

Directive

```
 app.directive('check',function(){
    return {
            restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        if(scope.$last){
       alert(scope.$index+1);//count value
       }
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Yeah. This might work, but this is better I guess:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383969/4382683

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Actually I didnt search it on SO ,I saw your question I gave answer according to that although my answer also works