# find length of filtered result angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat with fliter like below,

**HTML**

```
  <li  ng-repeat="article_data in articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter">
   {{article_data.article_title}}
 </li>
```

**Javascript**

```
ey.filter('ArticleFilter', function(){

return function(items, filters){

    var arrayToReturn = []; 
    if(value.article_title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filters.search_text.toLowerCase())==0)
     arrayToReturn.push(value);

return arrayToReturn;
}})
```

I need to check the result is empty or not,and show a message .Is it possible to do? I have tried `{{articles.length}}` but this is not the length of filtered result.

Comment: what is `value`? in your filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,

```
<li  ng-repeat="article_data in articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter as filteredResults">
   {{article_data.article_title}}
</li>

 {{ filteredResults.length }}
```

so you can have the code like this,

```
<ul>
    <li  ng-repeat="article_data in articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter as filteredResults">
       {{article_data.article_title}}
   </li>
</ul>

<p ng-if='filteredResults.length === 0'> No results.</p>
```

**Another way**

```
<li  ng-repeat="article_data in filteredResults = (articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter)">
       {{article_data.article_title}}
</li>

<ul>
    <li  ng-repeat="article_data in filteredResults = (articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter)">
       {{article_data.article_title}}
    </li>
</ul>

<p ng-if='filteredResults.length === 0'> No results.</p>
```

**PLUNK** : http://plnkr.co/edit/01JZZzBBOSfrpcM4dbVR?p=preview

Similar question, with another demo: [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

Comment: Will this filter work? Because you are checking the conditions before in `ng-if` and assigning the value later in `filteredResults` array ? I am eager to know about it.

Comment: yea simply remove the `ng-if` will solve it. thanks:)

Comment: Getting an error Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token at column 34 of the expression [articles | ArticleFilter:sfilter as filteredResults] starting at

Comment: can you share a punker example ?