# Filtering Tables: "No search results found"

Tags: html, angularjs, filtering, html-table

I have a `table` with a search bar which filters and displays the rows which it can match. This works fine but I want to implement that what if.

What if there's no search results from what you've decided to search. As it stand the `table` will simply display nothing. What I need is to instead display some text such as "No search results found." Ideally it would be a neat solution as opposed to an alert box or anything like that.

Any ideas? There's a plnkr below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="query[queryBy]" style="width: 400px;" placeholder="Search" />
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KFLbbz0k7ZBcETSvo3L9?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code like this

```
 <tr class="tt" ng-class="{even: $even, odd: $odd}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for more information on {{x.c}}." ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ng-repeat-start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProperty as displayTable">

                <td class="shrink"><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
                <td class="shrink">{{x.b}}</td>
                <td class="shrink"><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
                <td class="shrink">{{x.d}}</td>
                <td class="shrink">{{x.e}}</td>
                <td class="shrink">{{x.f}}</td>
                <p ng-if="!displayTable.length">no vals with this filter</p>

            </tr>
```

you can see your edited demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/64vaiPReW8MvhpRHBkQd?p=preview

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. When you type anything it will show the message with that.

Comment: Please check now @TheLimeTrees

Answer (score 1):

See [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

You can assign a new variable to the filtered expression

> `<div ng-repeat="person in filtered = (data | filter: query)">`

You can then show a new table row or div to check if this new query's length is 0

```
<tr ng-show='filtered.length == 0'>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Results</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I feel this is a viable method but I don't understand it well enough to apply it.