# how to display length of filtered data, with collection-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Can you help me find a way to display the length of filtered data, exactly like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data), but using `collection-repeat`.

The `alias` way doesn't seem to work:

```
<div>{{filtered.length}}</div>
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | orderBy:sort | filter:search | filter: selectBrand.brand | filter: selectName as filtered"  item-width="98%" item-height="75">
```

nor this way:

```
<div>{{filtered.length}}</div>
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in filtered =( prodataSelect | orderBy:sort | filter:search | filter: selectBrand.brand | filter: selectName )"  item-width="98%" item-height="75">
```

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to do won't work conceptually with the way that `collection-repeat` operates.  `collection-repeat` only renders the exact number of items that can fit on the display, which means internally there is a secondary filter.  the only way that this could possibly work would be if you pre-filtered the data in your controller, but that doesn't fit with the inline filters you have here.  I would say you are better off forking the `collection-repeat` directive and rewriting it for your purpose.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment. That's bad news for me. I like the flexibility of not doing the filtering in the controller... so I don't know

Comment: Good news, it is working. <ion-item class="next_no_padding" collection-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | unique: 'Id' | orderBy: ['-id', currentSortFilter]))"> and then {{filteredVacatures.length}}

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it's suppose to be working:

```
<ion-item class="next_no_padding" collection-repeat="item in (filteredItems = (items | unique: 'Id' | orderBy: ['-id', currentSortFilter]))">
```

And then somewhere on the same page:

```
{{filteredItems.length}}
```

Goodluck