# AngularJS: Get size of complex filtered array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a complex set of filters on an ng-repeat. I'm trying to get the count of the data set as it is filtered via each select list.

Here's my ng-repeat:

```html
  <div class="trials-item {{class}}" ng-repeat="data in dataObject | byCountry : selectRegion | byRegion : selectState | byCity : selectCity | filterBy:['Phase']: selectPhase | filterBy:['Compound']: selectCompound | filterBy:['TherapeuticArea', 'TherapeuticArea_2',]: selectTherapy : 'strict' | unique: 'Id' | orderBy:'Phase' : reverse track by $index " ng-class="{'open':$index == selectedRow}" id="anchor-{{$index}}" >
```

Trying to use {{ data.length }} doesn't work. I've tried to use some of the solutions detailed in this post: [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data) , but they all deal with a much simpler set of filters, and if they would work with my filter set above, I must not be getting the syntax/order correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to assign a variable towards the filtered `dataObject`, and make sure to enclose the assignment expression with a parenthesis after the `in` key word and before the `track` key word.

```
<div class="trials-item {{class}}" ng-repeat="data in (filteredData = (dataObject | byCountry : selectRegion | byRegion : selectState | byCity : selectCity | filterBy:['Phase']: selectPhase | filterBy:['Compound']: selectCompound | filterBy:['TherapeuticArea', 'TherapeuticArea_2',]: selectTherapy : 'strict' | unique: 'Id' | orderBy:'Phase' : reverse)) track by $index " ng-class="{'open':$index == selectedRow}" id="anchor-{{$index}}" ></div>
Result: {{ filteredData.length }}
```

**Update**

In case you're having problems with the scope of your variables, create an object `$scope` variable that stores the filtered data.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.filtered = {};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="trials-item {{class}}" ng-repeat="data in (filtered.data = (dataObject | byCountry : selectRegion | byRegion : selectState | byCity : selectCity | filterBy:['Phase']: selectPhase | filterBy:['Compound']: selectCompound | filterBy:['TherapeuticArea', 'TherapeuticArea_2',]: selectTherapy : 'strict' | unique: 'Id' | orderBy:'Phase' : reverse)) track by $index " ng-class="{'open':$index == selectedRow}" id="anchor-{{$index}}" ></div>
Result: {{ filtered.data.length }}
```

Comment: This doesn't bomb the query, but it also doesn't give me a value returned on the filteredData.length output.

Comment: If I may ask, is the result of the `filteredData` an `object` or an `array`?

Comment: If `filteredData` is undefined, then surely the `ng-repeat` result should be empty as well. If that's the case then the problem isn't in the assignment but in the filters.

Comment: What's the scope of filteredData - ie, what would I use in the console.log to get the value/type? I am getting a data set back, so it must have some value. I suspect I have the wrong $scope for logging. Was using console.log($scope.filteredData);