# angular: sum of ng-repeat filtered list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I can calculate sum of property in `ng-repeat` list like this:

```
<table ng-init="total=0">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td ng-init="$parent.total = $parent.total + item.Amount">
            {{item.Amount}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However this does not work, when `items` are filtered: `ng-repeat="item in items | filter: search"`

The reason is, that `<table>` element is initialized only once, while `<tr>` each time the list is filtered. Because of that, the sum is not set to 0 when filtering is applied.

Is there some event/directive, which is called when filtering is applied? I use this "calculate totals" functionality very often and wish to avoid writing `calculateTotals()` function several times in my controllers and directives.

Comment: I believe you are looking for what is outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data

Comment: How do you configure search filter, is it just one input with ngModel?

Comment: `search` filter is object with multiple properties and `items` list is a list of objects with the same structure as `search`.

Comment: This is really an [abuse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) of `ng-init`. Why don't you just calculate it (and re-calculate when `search` changes) in the controller?

Comment: i use this functionality on dozens of places throughout the application, so i wish to avoid writing function to calculate total in every directive

Comment: Then maybe you should create a factory/service with this generic functionality, and inject when necessary