# AngularJS - Get object index in custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have made a custom filter in controller but can't get index or size of iterated json. Calling `program.length` gets me undefined. Any ideas?

```
$scope.filterFn = function(program){
    if(case){
        return true;
    }
    console.log(program.length);//undefined
    return false;       
};
```

Comment: 1) case is a reserved keyword, you cannot use it as a variable name. 2) how are you calling the filter?

Comment: "Case" is just a placeholder. Filter is working as it should. I just need json object length.

Comment: is program a json?

Comment: Yes it is. I got length in http.get and then passed it to filter, it is the only way i got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

try to use this code to get object length.

```
Object.keys(program).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

try : [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data), so you can access size by `$scope.filtered.length` like the example.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any more filters before this? Coz previous filters decide input for next filter?

Answer (score 0):

The length() method is only available on an array [].

In this case you are trying to get the size of a json object {}, please note this does not have a length. If you need to see how many items exist in this object, you can try to first convert all the keys into an array by using `Object.keys(program)` which will give you an array.

If `program` originally looked like this:
{
 foo: 'some value',
 bar: 'another value'
}

using `Object.keys(program)` will give you `['foo', 'bar']` On this array you can now call the length method, so that you have  `Object.keys(program).length`, which in this case would give you 2.