# can't access ng-init value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-init

I am new to Angular.js . Trying to print total number of the rows but can't access the `ng-init` variable (ct). last span tag is not showing the value of {{ct}}. Did I miss anything ?

```
<div id="test-area" ng-controller="mycontroller" >
        <input type="number" step="1" max="5" min="1" ng-model="count" style="width:50px;"/>

        <input type="number" step="1" max="4" min="0" ng-model="indexFrom" style="width:50px;"/>
       <table class="tab1">
           <thead>
            <th>Name</th>  <th>Id</th>  <th>Address</th>  <th>Number</th> 
               <th>Date</th>
           </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | limitTo:count:indexFrom " ng-init="parent=user;$parent.ct=$index">
        <td>{{user.name | uppercase}}</td>   
        <td> {{user.id | number }}</td> 
        <td>{{user.address |lowercase}}</td> 
            <td ng-bind="parent.marks[0].it |currency:'$'">
            </td>
            <td class="ng-bind:user.bs | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'">

            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
           <br/>
        <span class="gray">Total Row Number : {{ct}} | From {{indexFrom}} to {{indexFrom+count}} </span>
        <br/>



    </div>
```

js :

```
(function(){

    var app=angular.module("Myapp",[]);
    var mycontrol=function($scope){
        $scope.users=users;
        $scope.increment=increment;
        $scope.change=change;
        $scope.count=3;
        $scope.indexFrom=0;
    }
    //marks increment
    var increment=function(marks){
        marks.it+=1;
    }
    //id increment
    var change=function(num){
       num.id=Number(num.id)+1;
    }
    var users=[{
            name:"Nihar", 
            id:"123",
            address:"New Town",
            bs:new Date("April 30 1993"),
            marks:[{it:90},{it:88},{it:97}]
        },{
            name:"Nilanjan",
            id:"194",
            address:"Baguiati",
            bs:new Date("July 20 1993"),
            marks:[{it:94},{it:65},{it:82}]
        },{
            name:"Raktim",
            id:"129",
            address:"Tegharia",
            bs:new Date("September 17 1993"),
            marks:[{it:97},{it:81},{it:79}]
        },{
            name:"Kaushik",
            id:"126",
            address:"Howrah",
            bs:new Date("October 10 1992"),
            marks:[{it:81},{it:89},{it:78}]
        },{
            name:"Abhishek",
            id:"287",
            address:"Dum Dum",
            bs:new Date("December 25 1994"),
            marks:[{it:91},{it:68},{it:87}]
        }];
    app.controller("mycontroller",mycontrol)



    }());
```

Comment: may we see the JS?

Comment: To further expand upon Danny's answer:  we have 0 clue what is wrong, because yo haven't shown us the most important aspect of the code.  You have a javascript question, yet you show us no javascript.

Comment: sure, I am gonna add The Js

Comment: This answer should work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19517533/373655

Comment: Nihar , are you able to see users table ? if i am not wrong, you are able to see users table but not the row total table  right??

Comment: yes Naga , you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
var app=angular.module("Myapp",[]);
```

to

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8285/).

**EDIT:**
Naga is correct, it would work with `MyApp` as well.  The reason why `Myapp` does not work is because of the way Angular handles the directive names.  On the Javascript side, Angular converts your names to **camel case**, which basically means the first letter is lowercase, and the next letter of each "word" in the variable is uppercase.  When the values are represented in HTML, they follow the HTML standard of being **dash delimited**, where each letter is lowercase, and words are separated by `-` characters.  You can also use colons (`:`) or underscores (`_`), but hyphens are the most common.

When you write `Myapp` or `myapp` in your Javascript, Angular normalizes that to `myapp` in the HTML.  But when you have `MyApp` or `myApp`, it becomes `my-app` in the HTML.

You can use whichever capitalization you like, so long as the HTML and Javascript match.

Comment: it works with anycase , it is not the issue with the myApp case - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXdVzj  check this once

Comment: Can you please Explain , why it's happening ?