# angular hide when filtered array is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple `ng-repeat`s which use a custom filter and I would like to hide the list. Each list has its own `someScopeValue` value which is used to determine if a repeated item should be included (or filtered out).

My first attempt doesn't work and it's clear why not (items is only filtered in the `ng-repeat` and `ng-show` doesn't know about this:

```
<!-- this is clearly not smart logic -->
<ul ng-show="items.length">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | customFilter:someScopeValue">text</li>
</ul>
...
<ul ng-show="items.length">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | customFilter:someScopeValue">text</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to also apply the filter to the `ng-show`? Here are some ideas I have but curious if there's a best practice or smarter way to do this:

```
<!-- this would filter the list somewhere in each <ul> scope -->
<ul ng-show="filteredList.length">
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredList">text</li>
</ul>
```

Or, maybe I can use `ng-init` in some smarter way?

```
<!-- this filters the list on-the-fly for each <ul> using some scope function -->
<ul ng-init="filteredList = filter(items, someScopeValue)" ng-show="filteredList.length">
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredList">text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can created a new variable on your scope that will be the filtered array like this:

```
<ul ng-show="filteredItems.length">
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:someScopeValue as filteredItems">{{item.value}}</li>
  <li>Extra</li>
</ul>
```

When doing something like this you will have a `$scope.filteredItems` created.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tf723v62/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not changing the data after you sort the data you could manipulate the array first inside the controller. Then just use your first suggestion of ng-show="filteredList.length".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the route I went with your question. I set a watch on a list in scope that was being modified by the filter, and based the show on another variable that was holding the length. Here's an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamescoot/yrq96pq9/).

```
  $scope.counter = $scope.items.length;

  $scope.$watch("items.length", function(newValue, oldValue) { 
    $scope.counter = newValue;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ng-init` or introduce a [variable in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data). But I would recommend to filter your data inside the controller and expose the filtered array to the template. Especially if you have to hide the parrent `<ul>` element.