# AngularJS - Custom filter for multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angular-filters

As you can see below is my JSON formatted data file.

You also can see that there's a root object called **servers** which contains two arrays.

There's another array within this array called **players**.

data.json

```
{ "servers" : [ { "age" : 44,
        "mapname" : "Las Venturas",
        "num" : 1,
        "online" : true,
        "players" : [ { "admin" : false,
            "cop" : true,
            "id" : 2,
            "level" : 10,
            "name" : "MariusTudor77",
            "registered" : true,
            "since_connect" : 3545,
            "skill" : "Police Officer",
            "spawned" : true
            },
            { "admin" : false,
            "cop" : false,
            "id" : 3,
            "level" : 0,
            "name" : "bananasinpajamas",
            "registered" : true,
            "since_connect" : 6726,
            "skill" : "Hitman",
            "spawned" : true
            },
            { "admin" : false,
            "cop" : false,
            "id" : 4,
            "level" : 0,
            "name" : "Milka2005Hewew",
            "registered" : false,
            "since_connect" : 177,
            "skill" : "Pick Pocket",
            "spawned" : true
            }
        ],
        "worldtime" : "11:00"
    },
    { "age" : 44,
        "mapname" : "Los Santos",
        "num" : 2,
        "online" : true,
        "players" : [ { "admin" : false,
            "cop" : false,
            "id" : 0,
            "level" : 0,
            "name" : "[_tayyab_]",
            "registered" : true,
            "since_connect" : 4063,
            "skill" : "Car Jacker",
            "spawned" : true
            },
            { "admin" : false,
            "cop" : false,
            "id" : 2,
            "level" : 10,
            "name" : "furkan",
            "registered" : false,
            "since_connect" : 1750,
            "skill" : "Mechanic",
            "spawned" : true
            }
        ],
        "worldtime" : "11:00"
    }
]}
```

On my website I'm loading this file from an extern URL using http from Angular (local for temp).

To show players from array [0] and [1] I'm using concat to mix them.

```
$http.get("api/players.php")
    .then(function (res) {

        vm.s1 = res.data.servers[0];
        vm.s2 = res.data.servers[1];

        vm.players = vm.s1.players.concat(vm.s2.players);

        vm.loading = false;
    });
```

Here's my loop where I list this vm.players.

```
<li ng-if="vm.players.length" ng-repeat="player in vm.players | filter: search | orderBy: 'name'">
    <a href="#">{{ player.name }} ({{ player.id }})</a>
</li>
```

On my website I have **four checkboxes**.

- Server 1 (Unchecked should not list array [0])
- Server 2 (Unchecked should not list array [1])
- Players (Unchecked should not list admin: false)
- Admins (Unchecked should not list admin: true)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checkbox.s1"> Server 1
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checkbox.s2"> Server 2
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checkbox.player"> Players
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.checkbox.admin"> Admins
```

I don't know how to do this. I tried to create a custom filter, but didn't work.

**Or if you know a better way please post it here.**

Comment: Please create the plunker with some dummy data

Comment: Here https://embed.plnkr.co/5iZk3f4jyZk3K6i8ebbp/ Make the window bigger to see the side panel. It's responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with @VSO, you will need to add the server to the player object to filter on the server.

I added this server property to the player objects and then created a custom filter for your requirements. It definitely works, but it's not super pretty, but should give you a good idea of how to structure things for a custom filter for manipulating data.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

https://embed.plnkr.co/2cY7ZGHiDaazjeafESMI/

I turned on server1, server2, admin, and player by default. You can adjust this in the following object:

```
$scope.cnrFilterObj = {
  admin: true,
  players: true,
  server1: true,
  server2: true
};
```

Comment: Good stuff guys. I like this solution.

Comment: Can you also make one little thing? The place where it shows Online Players (AMOUNT) should be based on filtered items.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data

Edit: Actually, it's not that simple because you have multiple filters...

Comment: check updated plunker. you need to create a `cnrFilterObjects` object on the fly and then we can use `cnrFilterObjects.length` to get the length of the current filtered items. this should work for checkboxes and search.

Comment: is this what you were looking for @Eucar?

Answer (score 1):

Either I don't understand the question, or you are going about it the wrong way. You can't POSSIBLY filter by server on an array that doesn't know what server the players came from (`vm.players`). If you want to concat the arrays, assign each player the server they came from beforehand. Then simply filter by the new `player.serverNumber` property:

```
        vm.s1 = res.data.servers[0];
        vm.s2 = res.data.servers[1];

        vm.s1.players.forEach(function (player) {
            player.serverNumber = 1; 
        });

        vm.s2.players.forEach(function (player) {
            player.serverNumber = 2; 
        });

        vm.players = vm.s1.players.concat(vm.s2.players);

        vm.loading = false;
```

And here is your html with some changes. Try out the new filter:

```
   <li ng-if="vm.players.length" ng-repeat="player in vm.players | filter: search | filter:{ serverNumber: 1}:true" | orderBy: 'name'">
                <a ng-click="vm.userInfo(player.name)" href="#" ng-if="player.admin" class="admin-icon">{{ player.name }} ({{ player.id }})</a>
                <a ng-click="vm.userInfo(player.name)" href="#" ng-if="!player.admin">{{ player.name }} ({{ player.id }}) ({{ player.serverNumber }})</a>
            </li>
```

[PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/OEE5nAvaUGuFothf7xS2?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, can you also show an example for filter? Should I rename the checkboxes like vm.serverNumber or smth like this?

Comment: Hey, I just added the filter for you. I recommend the checkbox simply triggering the filter. Define the filter value just like the other filter in a $scope.vm var and then toggle it when checkbox is checked/unchecked. I didn't see your checkboxes in the plunk. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I mean the filter should work based on checkboxes. When server 1 is checked it should list only serverNumber: 1 and when server 1 and server 2 are checked. It should list serverNumber: 1 and serverNumber: 2

Comment: I'll give you rep and mark as correct answer. You really helped me. It would be better if you'd also do that with checkboxes, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ty for rep, but check back, I am working on a solution for you.

Comment: Okay, I will wait here.

Comment: david got it =)