# Column total in table ng-repeat when filter in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I am getting column (Course fee) total at the end of the table when we load page first time, If we use filter, then column total is not getting reset. It should work if we use filter for all the columns

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtlr">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
<table>
<tbody ng-init="total=0"></tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="student in student_data|filter:search|limitTo:'10'">
    <td>{{student.table}}</td>
    <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>       
    <td ng-init="$parent.total = ($parent.total-0) + (student.course_fee-0)">    
     {{student.course_fee}}
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Total Course fee</td><td>{{total}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtlr', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.student_data = [{
    "student_id": "12508",
    "name": "AKILA",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "5000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "ygen",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "343535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "2500"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12513",
    "name": "KASTURI.M",
    "course": "NTT-Online",
    "course_fee": "11500",
    "percentage": "17.391304347826",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "34333353",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "2000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12611",
    "name": "SUDHA S",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "7000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "3353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "8000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12692",
    "name": "CHRISTOPHER SUNIL",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "15000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "3000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12693",
    "name": "PREMKUMAR J",
    "course": "Diploma EC",
    "course_fee": "12050",
    "percentage": "8.298755186722",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "JOHN AMARANATH",
    "mobile": "353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "1000"
  }]
});
```

**[My JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshraj/jbn06dj8/13/)**

Comment: Please add more code to your questions,

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right. See if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data) is what you want.

Comment: We are not clear with what you mean by count. Couldn't see any count variable being used in your code.

Comment: where is you used column count?

Comment: I need column total for course fee, Same is initialized in 4th column and displaying in 2nd row, U can see my JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your requirement, your total number should be changed along with the filtered students.

For filtering all the fields you can use the `strict filter`, you can filter all the fields using `$` parameter.

Here is the code I have for you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtlr', function($scope, $http, filterFilter) {

  $scope.studentdata = function(search) {
    var found = filterFilter($scope.student_data, {
      $: search
    });
    if (search == undefined) {
      var found = $scope.student_data;
    }
    console.log(found)
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
      var student = found[i];
      total += parseInt(student.course_fee);
    }
    return total;
  }

  $scope.student_data = [{


    "student_id": "12508",
    "name": "AKILA",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "5000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "ygen",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "343535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "2500"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12513",
    "name": "KASTURI.M",
    "course": "NTT-Online",
    "course_fee": "11500",
    "percentage": "17.391304347826",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "34333353",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "2000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12611",
    "name": "SUDHA S",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "7000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "3353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "8000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12692",
    "name": "CHRISTOPHER SUNIL",
    "course": "Cancelled",
    "course_fee": "15000",
    "percentage": "0",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "",
    "mobile": "353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "3000"
  }, {
    "student_id": "12693",
    "name": "PREMKUMAR J",
    "course": "Diploma EC",
    "course_fee": "12050",
    "percentage": "8.298755186722",
    "University": "",
    "partner": "YGEN",
    "infocenter": "",
    "father": "JOHN AMARANATH",
    "mobile": "353535",
    "sem": "0",
    "table": "noble",
    "total_paid": "1000"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtlr">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search" ng-change="total=0">
<table>
<tbody ng-init="total=0"></tbody>

 <tr ng-repeat="student in student_data|filter:search|limitTo:'10'">
  <td>{{student.table}}</td>
  <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
  <td>{{student.name}}</td>  
    <td>{{student.course_fee}} </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2"></td><td>Total</td><td>{{studentdata(search)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
```

**Please run this code**

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbn06dj8/16/)

Comment: Thanks Sravan, I tried but it is working for name filter only not for others, It should work if we filter all column

Comment: Thanks u so much Sravan