# How to know the length of a filtered array in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a search bar that lets users filter based on their entry using angular. Now I want to be able to display a message like "Nothing matches your search" when the search word entered by the user doesn't match anything in the array.

I tried monitoring a user's input using ng-change and then I loop through the array searching every parameter for the user's input but that doesn't work out. Here's a sample of my code.

html

```
<input ng-model="search" ng-change="check(search)">
<h4 ng-if="found === 0 ">Nothing matches your search</h4>
<div ng-controller="imCtrl" ng-repeat="imprest in imprests | filter:search">
    <h2>{{imprest.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

controller

```
var office = angular.module('Office');

office.controller('imCtrl',[$scope,function('$scope'){
     $scope.imprests = [
          {name:'John'},
          {name:'Peter'}
     ]

     $scope.check = function (word) {
        var found = 0
        $scope.searching = true
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.vendorForms.length; i++) {
            if($scope.imprests[i].name.includes(word){
                found++
            } 
        }
        $scope.found = found
        $scope.searching = true
        $scope.done = true
    }
})
```

Is it possible to know the length of the filtered array so I can display a message?

Comment: You can check this answer -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alias:

```
ng-repeat="imprest in imprests | filter:search as filtered"
```

Then you can access:

```
{{filtered.length}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an filter function and use it to filter your array in angular code, and then check it's length.

```
$scope.myFilter(){
   // ... here your logic 
   // you need to compare with $scope.search
   // and then return the new array and check it's length
}
```

in markup you can use like

```
<div ng-controller="imCtrl" ng-repeat="imprest in myFilter()">
    <h2>{{imprest.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `(imprests | filter:search).length == 0` to do this and then instead of your `ng-change` function you can simply add an `ng-show` to show the error, like so:

```
<input ng-model="search">
<h4 ng-if="found === 0 ">Nothing matches your search</h4>
<div ng-controller="imCtrl" ng-repeat="imprest in imprests | filter:search" ng-show="(imprests | filter:search).length !== 0">
    <h2>{{imprest.name}}</h2>
</div>
<div ng-show="(imprests | filter:search).length === 0">
    <h2>No results found</h2>
</div>
```