# Display AngularJS ng-repeat filter length for multiple filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat with multiple filters like below:

```
Active Items Found: {{totalActiveItems}}
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFilter | filter:{active:true}">
    {{item.title}}
</div>
```

I'm trying to store the total count outside of the ng-repeat in the `totalActiveItems` variable.

I saw this answer: [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

But it doesn't seem to show how to do it for multiple filters.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in a temporary variable in view and display the length using an expression .

```
Active Items length: {{totalItems.length}}
<div ng-repeat="item in totalItems=(items | filter:searchFilter | filter:{active:true})">
    {{item.title}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing the array resulting in the filter works fine even if you're using multiple filters :

```
Active Items Found: {{items.length}}
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchFilter | filter:{active:true} as filtered">
    {{item.title}}
</div>
Items found after filtering : {{filtered.length}}
```