# Getting size of JSON file in AngularJs returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Hi I'm currently learning AngularJS and JS in general and I'm trying to return the number of entries in a JSON file. The JSON file looks like that:

```
{
  "title": "Watching the Wheels",
  "artist": "John Lennon",
  "year": "1981",
},
{
  "title": "Way Over Yonder in the Minor Key",
  "artist": "Billy Bragg & Wilco",
  "year": "1998",
},
{
  "title": "We Are Never Ever Getting Back Together",
  "artist": "Taylor Swift",
  "year": "2012",
},
{
  "title": "We're Going To Be Friends",
  "artist": "The White Stripes",
  "year": "2001",
}
```

And i'm displaying it on a page and have to ability to do an instant search (which works). I just want it to return the number of entries. It's currently returning `19` and there's about 200 entries in the JSON file.

My html file looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app ="ngApp">
<head>
<title>First AngularJS Application</title>
<script src= "/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
<!--<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>-->
<title>Angular - INDEX</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
Artist: <input type="text" ng-model="artist"><br /> # of songs: <span>{{count}}</span>
Order by:
<a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'artist'">Artists</a>
<a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'year'">Year</a>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in artists | filter: artist | orderBy: predicate" >
        {{ artist.artist }} | {{ artist.title }} | {{artist.year}}
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
var ngcontr = angular.module('ngApp', []);
    ngcontr.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data.json')
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.artists = res.data;
            });
        $scope.predicate = 'year';
        $scope.count = Object.keys(ngcontr).length;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any help. Also it is possible to have the count updated as the search is updated?

Comment: You are getting the number of keys of your Angular app instance, not of your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the lenght of array not the object keys,

```
 $http.get('data.json')
 .then(function (res) {
    $scope.artists = res.data;
    $scope.count = $scope.artists.length;
});
```

Comment: That was easy. Do you know how I can get that number to update automatically when the search is being done?

Comment: it will automatically update the count whenever you get the response

Comment: It's not updating the count, unfortunately. It's an instant search btw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data

Comment: Mark as answer if this helped