# To display number of table items using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I display number of table item on a web page, something like: 20/67, where "20" is the current items on the page and "67" the total number of objects in the array.

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="mydata in data | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | linitTo: pageSize">
            <td>{{ $index + serial }}</td>
            <td>{{mydata.name}}</td>
            <td>{{mydata.age}}</td> 
<tr>  

<div class="pagenumber">
            <strong><p>Page info: {{ pageSize }}/{{ data.length }}</p></strong>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.data = data;
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.pageSize = 20;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.serial = 1; 
    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
            $scope.serial = $scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize
                    - ($scope.pageSize - 1);
        });
```

Since my total items are 67, them I'm having 20, 20, 20, 7 items per page.

Going by my HTML code, the "pageSize" will always give 20 which was the size specified in the controller.

How can I fix the code so that I get e.g 7/67 for the last page. As in, counting the number of items on every page?

Comment: How the table "knows" to display 7 items in the last page? Which code does that?

Comment: That was my question, I don't want to use "pageSize" in my HTML bcs it will always display 20.

Comment: I understand but your table / list "knows" to display only 7 items in the last page or not? Can you show the html code of the table / list?

Comment: I want to display the number under the table..... Right now im getting 20/67 even if the table items are 7

Comment: Addey, I get it. Let me ask this in a different way. Are you using some plugin to generate the table or you're doing it by yourself? Can you show the code of the table? I'm asking because maybe there is an easy way to get that data from the table functionality.

Comment: @Mosh Feu, that was my code. I used "serial" in the controller for page numbering. I just need help with displaying the actual number of items below the table, either its 20 or less.

Comment: Now, with the html is much more clear :) I think that this is the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19517533/863110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

controller:

```
    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage * $scope.pageSize < data.length) {
            $scope.currentPageSize = $scope.pageSize;
        }
        else {
            $scope.currentPageSize = data.length % $scope.pageSize
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="pagenumber">
        <strong><p>Page info: {{currentPageSize}}/{{ data.length }}</p></strong>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of $scope.currentPageSize Right now?

Comment: Addey, `doesn't work` means nothing.. What it does show? Is this throw an error??

Comment: @MoshFeu, My idea is to calculate the number of values on the current page, by the total. How he knows the total doesn't matter.

Comment: @MiriGold sorry, my question was to Addey. Your calculation is right 

Comment: @Addey, doesn't work means nothing.. What it does show? Is this throw an error??Do you mean that the number of `currentPageSize` or the table still have all the rows instead of respecting the page size and present top 20?

Comment: @MiriGold, see I used "$scope.serial" to start the table index number from 1 and not 0. When I used ur solutions, the current page displayed 0/67 and the other pages displayed just 17/67. That was why I said it was not working. Do you have a better solution ??

Comment: Sorry. The solution I wrote is just for calculating the last page.
I fixed it. try now.