# With an array of objects, how to count the number elements with active property true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't know the best way to problem solved.( Filter, ng-repeat or any method?)

```
<div>Number of active elements: {{product.length}} </div> //number of all elements
<div>Number of inactive elements: {{product.length}} </div> //number of all elements
```

Array example:

```
$scope.product=[
      {
       "name":"apple",
       "id":1,
       "active":false
      }, 
      {
        "name":"orange",
        "id":2,
        "active":true
      },
      ....
    ]
```

How to get the number of active products and number of inactive products? Which is the best and simple way?
Thank you!

Comment: `product.filter(p=>p.active).length` and `product.filter(p=>!p.active).length` should do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display length of filtered ng-repeat data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316363/how-to-display-length-of-filtered-ng-repeat-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use angularjs filter and then count.

```
<div>Number of active elements: {{(product | filter:{active:true}).length}} </div> //number of all elements
<div>Number of inactive elements: {{(product | filter:{active:false}).length}} </div> //number of all elements
```

In case you are filtering strings and want to apply a strict search, then use below.

```
<div>Number of active elements: {{(product | filter:{active:true}:true).length}} </div> //number of all elements
<div>Number of inactive elements: {{(product | filter:{active:false}:true).length}} </div> //number of all elements
```