# How to get count of an object values in ng-repeat template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have code `<span ng-repeat="(key,value) in obj">{{value}}</span>` where value is a number. I want to display total of all values in a last span.

Any speedy answer?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866185/number-of-items-in-a-list-filtered-angularjs

Comment: I'm not expecting the length here, I need total count of values. For ex: 3,2,5 values repeated in span, the last span should display values count i.e 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using filters in AngularJs.
I'm going to give an example just below this.

Here is our controller:

```
function simplecontroller($scope)
{
    $scope.customer = [22, 21, 23];
    $scope.ar = 0;
    $scope.customer.forEach(function(val){ $scope.ar += val; });
}
```

and here is the html:

```
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customer">
    Name: {{cust}}
    </li>
    </ul>
Total Length: {{ar}}
```

I use expression `{{ar}}` to show total counts.

Comment: Based on your code, I don't need customer.length, I need customer[0].age + customer[1].age + customer[2].age = 66. and this should be done in template.

Comment: Without js(controller) edit? same thing in view.
like. make the use of "+=" operator in template

Answer (score -1):

May this will help you
**html**:

```
<span>total: {{total()}}</span>
```

**js**:

```
$scope.total = function() {
            var count = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.yourObj, function(val) {
                count += val;
            });
            return count;
      };
```

Comment: May be(I assume not). I think this kind of work should be done in js.