# Angular: <select ng-required="options.length"> with filter

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have:

```
<select name="club" id="club" ng-model="currentUser.club_id" ng-options="club.id as club.name for club in clubs | filter:{ country_id: currentUser.country_id }" required></select>
```

I'm happy with that, except that since I `filter` the `clubs` list, there are cases where `<select>` has no `<option>`, which implies that the `required` attribute makes the form unsubmittable.

I could do

```
<select ng-required="(clubs | filter:{ country_id: currentUser.country_id }).length"></select>
```

but I though maybe there is a more elegant way to do that. Something like:

```
<select ng-required="$element.options.length"></select>
```

Is my intuition correct? What's the way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866185/number-of-items-in-a-list-filtered-angularjs this is for ng-repeat but i guess u can apply it for ng-options too

Comment: Nice it works! Don't you want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: posted the answer  with reference glad it fixed your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try

```
ng-repeat="item in filtered = (items | filter:filterExpr)"
```

and then use

```
filtered.length
```

This works for `ng-options` too !

Hope this was helpful

Reference [Filter Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866185/number-of-items-in-a-list-filtered-angularjs)